# Disable csrf token in laravel - 419 Page Expired

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, csrf, csrf-token

I have a problem which started a couple of weeks ago.
At tirst sometime Laravel used to trow error **"419 Page Expired"** when I was trying to login and since a week it trows this error **"419 Page Expired"** everytime and I'm completly unable to login to my website.

[image]

Then I read on stackoverflow That I would go to `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` and add the following code to disable CSRF protection for all routes.

```
protected $except = [
    '*',
];
```

After adding this code it shows me:

```
 Redirecting to https://*****.com/home
```

And it redirects to the main page.
[image]

**Also I tried: config/session.php**

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '****.com'),
```

How to solve this problem or completly disable csrf verification?

Comment: you can remove that middleware from the `web` stack if you really want to .... its in `app/Http/Kernel.php` - `$middlewareGroups -> 'web'`, you will see it listed there

Comment: Now it keeps redirecting when I'm trying to login:  "Redirecting to https://*****.com/home"

Comment: Do you have a csrf token in your form?

Comment: Yes, I have. https://gist.github.com/amirandev/cbcfcc04516b1443d5679e463e7788fe